# Multiple network shares to single mount point?

Tags: centos, filesystems, mount, partition, bind-mount

How would I mount multiple network shares to single mount point?

#### Example

```
//10.50.154.6/data    42T   22T   21T  51% /mnt/data6
//10.50.154.7/data   8.1T  6.2T  1.9T  77% /mnt/data7
//10.50.154.8/data    33T   29T  4.6T  87% /mnt/data8
etc
```

These would be mounted or bound together:
`/mnt/data6`, `/mnt/data7`, `/mnt/data8` etc.. to `/mnt/dataALL`.

There are no directories with same name in network shares, but subdirs have identical names. So, I think there should be no conflicting over names.

What is the best practice for this kind of unified or layered configuration?

Comment: Have a look at [UnionFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UnionFS).

Comment: The example shows different mount-points: `/mnt/data6`, `/mnt/data7` and `/mnt/data8`.

Comment: Thank you! After some time on google checking unionfs, and some other similar options. unionfs-fuse works great for ubuntu 16.04 and centos 6.1

Comment: @dirkt, you should rewrite your answer as an answer.

Comment: @user2066657: I think that standards for an answer here would demand I explain how to use UnionsFS etc., and I was too lazy for that. If you (or the asker) would like to write a more detailed answer, please do so.